# Child elements insert in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET 5 with Entity Framework 7.
I have this models:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ChildModel Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual AnotherChildModel AnotherChild { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherChildModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to add ParentModel to database, it doesn't automatically add ChildModel and AnotherChildModel to database, while ParentModel completely correct in code, for example:

```
var parent = new ParentModel() { Children = new ChildModel() { AnotherChild = new AnotherChildModel() { Text = "sometext" }}};
```

So, simple `parentSet.Add(parent)` doesn't work, is there another way, except for manually adding all models in sets?

**EDIT:**

Exception I have:

```
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ParentModel_ChildModel_ChildrenId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet5-WebApplication1-922849d0-b7da-4169-8150-9a2d05240a47", table "dbo.ChildModel", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: No, you need to add child and parent class individually

Comment: The initializer you're using for `ChildModel` doesn't seem to match the model...

Comment: @David edited to correct

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers is this only one corrrect asnwer? Very sad, if it does.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers this is not true. EF is able to add graphs of objects by adding single "parent" object. The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I've just tested it on my test database and it works fine with my models. What type of exception you get?

Comment: @Szer added exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current RC1 version of EF7, `Add()` only recursively adds adhering objects in *collections* (i.e. true *children*), not *referenced entities*, as EF6 did.

So if you'd have the following model (that's more consistent with the names you chose) ...

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

... the children would also be added by the single statement `parentSet.Add(parent)`.

I don't know if this is intended behavior. The RC has already proven to come with issues a "release candidate" shouldn't have. But maybe it's an OO-inspired design decision that parents encapsulate their children and not the reverse.

Comment: very strange behaviour, when I can add only Collection of ChildModels, but not the ChildModel only. What should I do, if I want to add referenced entities, like Child and AnotherChild, too?

Comment: You have to add them explicitly, same way as you add `parent`.

Comment: Am I understand correct, that the same situation with cascade delete?

Comment: Cascaded delete is basically a database setting. You should be able to delete a parent only. I don't know if EF7 handles  this correctly, but that's an entirely different issue.